# Markerclusterer - Cluster markers + Custom Icons

Tags: php, google-maps, markerclusterer

is there any possibility to cluster markers until a predefined zoomlevel (e.g. from 0 to 7) and from that of to display **custom icons** which are not clustered.
in addition: if a marker is **not within** a cluster, there has to appear the custom icon, too.
furthermore: if possible the color/icon of the cluster should be selected by a variable committed by a **php script**

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html)?  Why is this tagged "kml" and "geoxml3"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a marker cluster in php:http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps.